# right justified and left zero filled in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000' + CAST([ID] as SYSNAME), 8) ID 
  FROM Table1
```

The above query makes a column right justified and left zero filled in sql server.
Can Some one let me know the equivalent in Oracle DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT LPAD(ID,8,'0') FROM Table1` may work for you.

Look at [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php) for lpad usage